# Java Typical Way to Access TCKs

Tags: java, oracle, jsr

I wanted to start implementing a specific JSR to start learning about different aspects that might be involved when doing so. To also get the satisfaction of knowing whether I succeeded, I'd need a TCK (Technology Compatibility Kit) to verify the implementation. According to the JCP Homepage this is only available to selected partners (I'm assuming commercial) or academic institutions.

How do private entities or in general Open Source projects get access to a TCK? What is involved and is this a task worth trying?

The old Sun pages for partner registration are down / link to generic Oracle sites, the closest thing I've found is https://java-partner.sun.com/support/login.action, which lacks a registration form / info.

Comment: I doubt it's worth trying. Run an existing implementation's unit/integration tests against your implementation, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access to a TCK as a non-commercial entity you can apply for the [*Compatibility Testing Scholarship Program*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-137188.html) of Oracle. If you are a commercial entity you will need to pay $35K per year to get access. I believe you also get access if you are a [JCP member](http://www.jcp.org/en/participation/membership) (which is more than just having an account on their site and requires filing some paperwork with Oracle).

I am not sure how and if this actually works. I am considering doing it myself, but I haven't yet had the time to deal with these bureaucratic hurdles.